# Skaffold setValues is getting missing helm values

Tags: skaffold

Skaffold `setValues` is getting missing helm values.

Instead of `setValues`, when I save the relevant values in the `values.yml` file and use `valuesFiles`, there is no problem and the rendering is successful.

I guess `setValues` doesn't recognize nested arrays. Please review the example below.

Why the `ingress.tls[0].hosts` doesn't exist?

#### skaffold.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta29
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  artifacts:
  - image: example
    jib: {}
    sync:
      auto: false
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
    - name: example
      chartPath: backend-app
      artifactOverrides:
        image: example
      imageStrategy:
        helm: {}
      setValues:
        ingress:
          enabled: true
          className: nginx
          hosts:
            - host: example.minikube
              paths:
                - path: /
                  pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          tls:
            - secretName: example-tls
              hosts:
                - example.minikube
```

#### skaffold run

```bash
skaffold run -v TRACE
```

```bash
# Output
[...]
[...]
[...]
DEBU[0106] Running command: [
helm --kube-context minikube install example backend-app --set-string image.repository=example,image.tag=6ad72230060e482fef963b295c0422e8d2f967183aeaca0229838daa7a1308c3 --set ingress.className=nginx --set --set ingress.enabled=true --set ingress.hosts[0].host=example.minikube --set ingress.hosts[0].paths[0].path=/ --set ingress.hosts[0].paths[0].pathType=ImplementationSpecific --set ingress.tls[0].secretName=example-tls]  subtask=0 task=Deploy
[...]
[...]
[...]
```

#### Ingress Manifest

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: "example.minikube"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: example
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Tracked as https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/7850

Comment: This is fixed now in Skaffold @ HEAD and will be available in v2.1.0+ https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/7850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed recently via the PR here:
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pull/8152

This is currently in skaffold in `main` and will be available in the `v2.1.0` Skaffold release (to be released `12/7/2022`) and onward

EDIT: `v2.1.0` release is delayed w/ some of the maintainers on holiday.  Currently planned to be available late Dec or early Jan

EDIT #2: `v2.1.0` is out now (`1/23/2023`)

Comment: Thanks aaron-prindle you are awesome!

Comment: The `v2.1.0` Skaffold release is now out (`1/23/2023`), sorry for the delay.  Thanks for your patience

Comment: I really thank you for your work, you have created a awesome tool.